# Wordpress - Redirect to previous page after login

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

On Woocommerce for Wordrpress, when you're on a product page and click to login, when you're login, you're redirected to your Dashboard page from your account and not the previous page that you was reading.

I'm trying to do that, redirect to the previous page before login or to home page if there is no previous page on my site.

I'v tried this but every time I'm redirected to the home page.

```
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect ) {
        $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Any idea ?

Comment: On the login form page I usually make a hidden input field which stores the last `$_SERVER['http_referrer']`. On the processing page for the login, just check if this input box contains anything, if it does, redirect to it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the `login_redirect` function like so, adapt according to your needs.

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_previous_page', 10, 1);

function redirect_previous_page( $redirect_to ){
    global $user;    
    $request = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

    if ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'administrator') ) ) {    
        return admin_url();    
    } elseif ( in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'subscriber') ) ) {    
        return $request;
    }     
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It comes in handy when you're linking to a product page from an e-newsletter and don't allow guest checkout.
I bypassed it using a plugin that brought the login up as a pop-up window - if it doesn't leave the page it doesn't need to redirect.